# Height of Div tags being ignored

Tags: css, html

I am sure this is something stupid I'm doing, but it's been quite a while since I messed with CSS. And for the life of me I cannot figure out why the div boxes are not displaying the right height (as specified in the CSS)...and why there is that black block of space between header divs and the columns.

Any help would be VERY appreciated! I know it's pretty bare-bones, I'm just trying to get the main layout down.

Thanks for any help!!
CSS:

```
#container { width: 1000px; margin: 30px auto 60px;}

    h1 { text-align: center;}

    #header { height: 200 px; width: 1000 px;  background-color: #993300}
    #mcol1 { height: 600; width: 500px; float: left; background-color: #2a9c3b;}
    #mcol2 { height: 600; width: 500px; float: left; background-color: #996666;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

<div id="header">
<h1> Name</h1>
</div>
<div id="mcol1">
<h1>Test1</h1>
</div>

<div id="mcol2">
<h1>Test2</h1>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Since I can't directly post pictures because I'm new, here's a link to how it's displaying: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0I85.jpg
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not

```
height: 200 px; 
height: 200;
```

but

```
height: 200px;
```

Comment: Thanks Everyone!!! I think this fixed it, although I also implemented the clear fix. I'm sure I will have more questions at some point. This community is awesome! I look forward to becoming more involved!

Answer (score 4):

Add **`px`** to every height value:

```
#header { height: 200px; width: 1000px;  background-color: #993300}
#mcol1 { height: 600px; width: 500px; float: left; background-color: #2a9c3b;}
#mcol2 { height: 600px; width: 500px; float: left; background-color: #996666;}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e9uEa/)

Answer (score 0):

Try and clear the floats on mcol1 and mcol2 by using this:

```
          <!-- html -->
          <div id="container">

            <div id="header">
              <h1> Name</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="mcol1">
              <h1>Test1</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="mcol2">
              <h1>Test2</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
           </div>

           <!-- css -->
           .clear{
             clear:both;
             height:0;
             line-height:1px;
           }
            #mcol1 { height: 600px; width: 500px; float: left; background-color:#2a9c3b;}
            #mcol2 { height: 600px; width: 500px; float: left; background-color: #996666;}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition you may want to add style overflow hidden to your divs especially for small divs in internet explorer

```
style = "overflow: hidden;"
```

and also you may want to download reset.css and include it in the head

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/reset.css"/>
```